# How to determine if image is using transparency on Javascript?

Tags: javascript, image, html5-canvas, transparency

I'd like to be able to detect if a logo type image has a transparent background or not, let's imagin that two similar images are `.png` files but one has a white background and another on has a transparent background, how would I be able to determine the one with transparency ?

I've tried using colorthief but it doesn't take transparency into account, so I thought doing it by myself on `canvas`. A first solution would be to convert the `png` file into `jpg` and if the background color of the `jpg` after being converted appear to be black then it's a transparent logo, but this might be a problem for users with black background and white logos. Is there a better solution than that ?

http://jsfiddle.net/9s5qf5cu/

**from png to jpg :**

```
var imageLoader = document.getElementById('imageLoader');
imageLoader.addEventListener('change', handleImage, false);

var canvas = document.getElementById('imageCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');


function handleImage(e){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event){
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function(){
            canvas.width = 100;
            canvas.height = 100;
            ctx.drawImage(img,0,0, 100, 100);
            document.getElementById("image").src = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
        }
        img.src = event.target.result;

    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);     
}
```

Comment: "A first solution would be to convert the png file into jpg" <-- For your information: JPEG does not have an alpha channel.

Comment: @Zomry I know that, but when converting a png file into jpg you get a black background if the image is transparent.

Comment: There are probably many ways to this, one would be to do what you suggest, perhaps by checking all the pixels and determening if a certain number of pixels have the same color as the background. Using another image as a background would make it highly unlikely that a large number of pixels are the same etc. The proper thing to do though, would be to send the image to the server, and use ImageMagick to check the alpha channel.

Comment: @Lindow You **don't get** a black background when converting it. It is the software or the algorithm you are going to use the one which decides to set a black background. But it could be pink!

Comment: @lilezek Yes I understand that, but I'm saying that in my case on the jsfiddle it's black and I could use that to detect if the background was transparent

Comment: _"but when converting a png file into jpg you get a black background if the image is transparent"_ - and how would that help you determine whether you had a PNG with a transparent background, or one that was black to begin with? Copying the PNG onto the canvas and going with getImageData and checking the alpha level of every single pixel would be a way to go I suppose (assuming copying an image that contains such transparent parts onto an empty canvas keeps those values intact.)

Comment: @CBroe Interesting, I didn't know you could check the alpha level of each pixels on canvas.

Comment: [getImageData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData) returns an [ImageData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData) object, and that has a `data` property containing a one-dimensional array of integers, R, G, B, and A value for each pixel, just one after the other.

Comment: _"but I'm saying that in my case on the jsfiddle it's black"_ - well that is likely because the program that produced your PNG simply put black pixels with an alpha value of zero there ... but that could be any other color as well, for example if the user of a graphics program selected an area via a "magic wand" tool by color and then made their selection transparent.

Comment: I'm guessing that's a bit problematic, any image inserted into a canvas that isn't from the same origin would be tainted, so any image used on JSFiddle would have to come from that origin

Comment: There's a demo on [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas), a little ways down the page

Comment: Should be simple enough to achieve, assuming you have the code to load the PNG onto canvas already (creating a canvas of the right dimensions) ... You get the image data, and then you can check in a simple for loop starting at 0, increasing the loop counter by 4 each time, whether the alpha value indicates no transparency at all for that pixel. If you encounter one, set a flag and break out of the loop ...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use this function by passing your context and your canvas. Then it will loop over the alpha channel until it finds an entry that is not completely opaque.

```
function hasAlpha (context, canvas) {
    var data = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height).data,
        hasAlphaPixels = false;
    for (var i = 3, n = data.length; i < n; i+=4) {
        if (data[i] < 255) {
            hasAlphaPixels = true;
            break;
        }
   }
   return hasAlphaPixels;
}
```

**Note**: this will not work if your canvas is tainted.

Comment: Thanks, I have some issue making it work : http://jsfiddle.net/9s5qf5cu/2/ what should I enter to context ?

Comment: In this function that would be `ctx`.

Comment: Every image I try seem to be transparent, even if it isn't

Comment: I see, I started with i at 0, while it should have started at 3. Try this version: https://jsfiddle.net/Zomry/g0mt5obw/