# What is the best way to set a fallback for a transparent image?

Tags: javascript, css, image, background, background-image

Currently, I'm using a 20px fallback image while the images are loading. The problem is for the transparent images. When they get loaded, they look blurry for their background image. Using dominant color or traced SVG causes the same problem differently. So, how can I use a fallback image for them without having these side effects?

One solution is removing the background when they are loaded. But is it a good solution?

A better solution maybe is to remove the background only for the transparent images. Is there any way to detect if the images are transparent using Node JS? So, that I can take action only for those images.

I'm using Gatbsy JS and the gatsby-remark-relative-images plugin to automate the image-optimization process. But it's not necessary to answer the question using the Gatsby APIs.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript there is a `load` event listener, your best bet may be to have an event listener for each of the 'img' elements which removes the fallback,

```
document.querySelectorAll('.loaded-img').forEach(elm => {
   elm.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
      event.target.previousElementSibling.remove() // This is generally bad practice IMO, 
      //here I'm assuming the fallback img is right before the actual img but for 
      //consistency may want to do something like 
      //event.target.parentElement.querySelector('.fallback-img').remove()
      //Could also just add a forwards animation to opacity 1 -> 1;
   }, { once:true }) // Only runs once per Image.
})
```

Alternatively could add a event listener to the parent like this,

```
document.querySelector('.img-parent').addEventListener('load', (event) => {
   if (event.target.classList == 'image-class') // ... Same as above
})
```

Comment: Hmm... It's a good answer. But I think if I could detect transparent images using JavaScript, I would have more options. Such as, I could make their background white. Or, I could apply your solution only for those by adding a class. But I can do these only if detecting transparency is possible in javascript!

Comment: Presumably you found this article already https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45122264/how-to-determine-if-image-is-using-transparency-on-javascript - It is possible to detect the "alpha" channel (which is what opacity relates to), however this is only used in a canvas - In theory you could create a canvas for each img element however I admit this is kind of jank and probably very laggy

Comment: Hmm... I found that article. But it's not really what I am looking for. And creating a canvas for every Img element is also not a solution.

Comment: If, using the solution above, you just change the style off the fallback image to be white or something then, the loaded img if its not fully opaque will have that style behind it however if it is fully opaque then you wont be able to see the white fallback image anyway?-  essentially change the style for all of them, and they will be covered up anyway by the opaque images

Comment: Are you telling me to use a white background instead of removing the background when the images get loaded? Well, both are the same to me.

Comment: Oh! I think you and I have forgotten that detecting transparency is something that we'll do in the Node JS runtime, not in browsers. So, is there any npm package that can do this? Such as sharp?